# User initiated background process in a web application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, multithreading, background

I have a java web application wired using Spring on Tomcat.

I need a way for a user to initiate a background process in the server and return a response to the user without waiting for the background process to complete.

The background process is programmed in java and integrated with my application.

Since i am using tomcat JMS is not an option. I'd rather not have to customize my tomcat installation for the sake of portability.

I could use Quartz or similar and check on a regular basis whether the process should run but i'd prefer something that started instantly.

I have tried spawning a new thread but it is not aware of my Spring beans.

What is the best way to go about this?

Thanks

Max

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring provides the [TaskExecutor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/core/task/TaskExecutor.html) abstraction for this sort of thing, which comes with a dozen or so different implementations for you to choose from (`ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` is probably what you want). It's up to you to use it correctly so that the tasks have access to the Spring context when they run.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds typical for an **Ajax** request. :-)

Your browser won't be waiting for the result...

Answer (score -2):

You could just fire a plain old Java Thread.

Comment: i guess the reason is , "You can do this fairly easily with a stand-alone Java application using threads, but you can't use threads in J2EE." - http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/activemq/.